# Batching Seq2Seq model with Tensorflow Experiment

Tags: tensorflow, batch-processing, distributed-computing, sequence-to-sequence

I'm trying to convert a [Seq2Seq model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq) I've run locally to use Tensorflow distrubution capabilities using [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators) and [Experiment](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment). The basic feature and targets are set up as follows:

```
for every input and response (translation or prompt and response):
  raw input -> tokenized input -> tokenized response -> raw response
```

Note:

- features will have a shape [number of buckets][number inputs @ bucket size][size of bucket for input]
- targets will have a shape [number of buckets][number responses @ bucket size][size of bucket for response]

A few questions:

1. Generally, are the Experiment class and Estimator interface recommended for handling this sort of model?
2. Can I set a training batch size with Experiment? It seems `train_steps` and `eval_steps` relate to iterations of training and evaluation. Is there another option that sets a batch size for those steps, or does Experiment compute a batch size internally/automatically?
3. I'm assuming the Experiment `train_input_fn` and `eval_input_fn` can be any [input_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn) that returns a feature dictionary and target tensor. In the case above, I really only need one feature tensor and one target tensor, which, since I am creating a custom Estimator, can be any shape so long as my Estimator's `model_fn` expects those shapes and can properly return loss from them. Is this correct?

Comment: It seems the **train** graph and **infer** graph are different from each other. Even, if you export the graph upon training, you could not use that graph for Inference. Correct me if I'm wrong.